# Android OpenGL ES, weird quality using 2D texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

after a long search, I didn't find any solution to my problem, so here it is:

I have the following sprite:

http://i46.tinypic.com/rmji2d.png&quot;">

but in my game with a OpenGLSurface, using 2d texture it looks like this:

http://i47.tinypic.com/2wqb9qs.png&quot;">

The options I'm using in my textures are these:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig confid) {
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glClearColor(255,255, 255,0);
gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

}

```
 public void loadTextures(GL10 gl, Context context) {
 gl.glGenTextures(textureCount, textures, 0);
    for (int loop = 0; loop < textureCount; loop++) {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[loop]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, // OpenGL docs.
                GL10.GL_NICEST);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap[loop], 0);
        bitmap[loop].recycle();
    }
}
```

**Is it only this weird because i'm scaling the image, making it shortier?
Is there anything i can do to have better graphics?**

ADDED the DRAW:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    for (int loop = 0; loop < sprites.size(); loop++) {
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        try {
            DevQuestSprite sprite = sprites.get(loop);
            sprite.update(screenHeight); // update enemy
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[sprite.curSprite]);
            float transx = (wRatio * sprite.x);
            float transy = (screenHeight * wRatio) - (wRatio * sprite.y)
                    - 1 / hRatio;
            gl.glTranslatef(transx, transy, 0.0f);

            sprite.draw(gl);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems so that your image links are in wrong order. That said, it might be best if you scaled down the original image closer to final rendered size. In general image editors act better with down scaling than OpenGL.

Comment: Ops, edited the links. 
But the problem is that i'm scaling it depending on the screen size, so I need a big one like the one i'm using..

Comment: In that case one quick change you could try is using BitmapFactory and its Options to downscale the image before assigning it to OpenGL texture. I'm afraid it doesn't provide any better quality though.

Comment: How about you show us your drawing code?

Comment: datenwolf,I edited the post, there it is.

Comment: You might want to use mipmapping when you scale down the texture by that much: http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-six-an-introduction-to-texture-filtering/

Comment: Michael, I read the link you provided and I Tried: gl.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
but i get this message: The method glGenerateMipmap(int) is undefined for the type GL10, is it possible to do it in GL10?

Comment: Generate the mipmaps by an image editor and load them at runtime. It is faster and gives max quality as you control the final look of the image.

Comment: When you say, "Generate the mipmaps" do you mean a DDS file? or a bunch of files of the same image with different sizes?